# Destroying Sessions Issue Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, session-variables

I'm having problems destroying the session, the link doesn't seem to work, the URL changes in the address bar from /dashboard to /log_out but the page does not redirect to the log in page. I'm rather baffled at this.

Dashboard View:

```
<% if logged_in? %>
    <% if request.env['mobvious.device_type'] == :mobile %>
        <div class="container" style="width: 90%" >
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td class="dash_cont">
                        <%= link_to "Logout", log_out_path %>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="dash_cont">
                        <h1 class="form-signin-heading" >Welcome to your personal Twitter Manager!</h1>
                        <p>Use this site to keep track of your followers, see how many posts they've made and many more features!</p>
                        <p>It's a really cool site, check it out! It's free!</p><br/><br/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    <% elsif request.env['mobvious.device_type'] == :desktop %>
        <div class="container" style="width: 70%;" >
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td class="dash_cont">
                        <%= link_to "Logout", log_out_path %>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="dash_cont">
                        <h1 class="form-signin-heading" >Welcome to your personal Twitter Manager!</h1>
                        <p>Use this site to keep track of your followers, see how many posts they've made and many more features!</p>
                        <p>It's a really cool site, check it out! It's free!</p><br/><br/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    <% end %>
<% else %>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.location.href="/"  // put your correct path in a string here
    </script>
<% end %>
```

Log In View:

```
<% if logged_in? %>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.location.href="/dashboard"  // put your correct path in a string here
    </script>
<% else %>
    <% if request.env['mobvious.device_type'] == :mobile %>
        <div class="container" style="width: 90%" >
            <table>
                <tr class="login-cont">
                    <td class="login-tcell">
                        <h1 class="form-signin-heading" >Log in</h1>
                        <%= form_tag sessions_path, class: "form-signin" do  %>
                            <%= text_field_tag :email, params[:email], class: "form-control", autofocus: "", required: "", placeholder: "Email address" %>
                            <%= password_field_tag :password, nil, class: "form-control", required: "", placeholder: "Password" %></br>
                            <p class="button"><%= submit_tag "Log in", class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" %></p>
                        <% end %>
                        <%= link_to "Register", "/sign_up" %>
                        <% if defined?(@error) %>
                            <div class="error">
                                <%= "*" + @error %> 
                            </div>
                        <% end %>
                        <% if defined?(@notice) %>
                            <div class="error">
                                <%= "*" + @notice %> 
                            </div>
                        <% end %>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    <% elsif request.env['mobvious.device_type'] == :desktop %>
        <div class="container" style="width: 70%" >
            <table>
                <tr class="login-cont">
                    <td class="login-tcell">
                        <h1 class="form-signin-heading" >Log in</h1>
                        <%= form_tag sessions_path, class: "form-signin" do  %>
                            <%= text_field_tag :email, params[:email], class: "form-control", autofocus: "", required: "", placeholder: "Email address" %>
                            <%= password_field_tag :password, nil, class: "form-control", required: "", placeholder: "Password" %></br>
                            <p class="button"><%= submit_tag "Log in", class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" %></p>
                        <% end %>
                        <%= link_to "Register", "/sign_up" %>
                        <% if defined?(@error) %>
                            <div class="error">
                                <%= "*" + @error %> 
                            </div>
                        <% end %>
                        <% if defined?(@notice) %>
                            <div class="error">
                                <%= "*" + @notice %> 
                            </div>
                        <% end %>
                    </td>
                    <td class="welcome-msg white">
                        <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
                        <h1 class="form-signin-heading" >Welcome to your personal Twitter Manager!</h1>
                        <p>Use this site to keep track of your followers, see how many posts they've made and many more features!</p>
                        <p>It's a really cool site, check it out! It's free!</p><br/><br/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Dashboard Controller:

```
class DashboardController < ApplicationController

    helper_method :logged_in?

    def new
    end
    def logged_in?
        if defined? session[:user_id]
            true
        else
            false
        end
    end
end
```

Sessions Controller:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

    helper_method :logged_in?

    # Use this to detect device type:
    # request.env['mobvious.device_type']

    def new
    end
    def create
        user = User.authenticate(params[:email], params[:password])
        if user
            session[:user_id] = user.id
            @notice = "Logged in!"
            redirect_to "/dashboard"
        else
            @error = "Invalid email or password"
            render "new"
        end
    end

    def destroy
        session[:user_id] = nil
        redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Logged out!"
    end
    def logged_in?
        if defined? session[:user_id]
            redirect_to "/dashboard"
        else
            redirect_to "/"
        end
    end
end
```

Routes:

```
TwitterApp::Application.routes.draw do
    get "dashboard/new"
    get "users/new"
    get "sessions/new"
    get "log_out" => "sessions#destroy", :as => "log_out"
    get "" => "sessions#new", :as => "log_in"
    get "sign_up" => "users#new", :as => "sign_up"
    get "dashboard" => "dashboard#new", :as => "dashboard"
    root :to => "sessions#new"
    resources :users
    resources :sessions
end
```

Comment: Conner, Ruby on Rails questions should not be tagged with Ruby. See the Ruby tag wiki. Please remove the ruby tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `defined?` to check for the presence of hash values. It will always return a non false value:

```
some_hash = { :some_key => nil }
defined? some_hash[:some_key] # => "method"
defined? some_hash[:i_dont_exist] # => "method"
```

See the [docs on this](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/Object.html#method-i-defined-3F) for more info.

In rails you can use `session[:user_id].present?`. This will check that the value at that key is not blank or nil. Also a better way to delete from the session is to call `delete` on it: `session.delete(:user_id)` or `session.clear` if you want to wipe everything.

Comment: Thanks dude, the defined? method was the problem, I didn't realise it only checked to see if variables were initialised, I thought it was to check to see if it had a value. Idiot, thanks man :)